# push notification with username and password

Tags: iphone, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I am developing an app for the iPhone that needs to notify the user when they have any new unread important messages, so i am wanting to use the push notification service. But the user has to sign in using a username and password which is then checked against the web service. Can I still use the push notification service if the user has to sign in with a username and password? And if i can is there any example code any where that does the  same thing using push notification with a username and password?

Comment: is the user automatically signed out when the app closes?

Comment: Yes, I don't understand what the problem is. The user gets a notification and clicks to view the message.  The app opens, and at that point the user can type in the username and password to actually view the message.  Or, is there a different flow than what I am describing there?

Comment: your described application flow is confusing. If you are using push notification why you need login, or if you are using login then why you need "push"

Comment: The comments add have actually helped thanks. And Yes the user automatically signs out on app close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually resolved this, not with a very good fix but with a fix that will work for the time being. I actually use local notification that runs using schedules and then when it receives a local notification it runs a processor to call to the webservice with the username and password.